# Uniform and nonuniform linear transformations

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I can't find an explanation of the difference between these two types of transformation.  If a linear transformation transforms a circle to an ellipse which kind of transformation is it?  (nonuniform?)  If it transforms a circle to a circle what kind is it? (uniform?)
I read the following in Visual Complex Analysis by Needham:

"Consider the effect of a uniform linear transformation on a circle $C$......The image curve... must be an ellipse..."

Is this correct?

Also in the same book it says:

"...a uniform linear transformation-corresponding to a constant matrix..."

Does constant matrix here mean just that the elements of the matrix are constants, or that they are constant and all equal?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my question myself

A *uniform* linear transformation does generally transform a circle to an ellipse, and is the same at all points of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  A nonuniform linear transformation varies over $\mathbb{R}^2$.